# How to use cppclean to find unused headers

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm looking for a tool to help detect unnecessary header includes in a large c++ code base. The other stackoverflow questions on this topic all suggest cppclean. So I've installed cppclean and I'm trying to use it but even on trivially wrong examples it doesn't give any results.

For example, here's what I'm trying to clean. The source file:

```
// foo.cpp
#include "bar.h"

void main() { };
```

And the header file:

```
// bar.h
class bar {
};
```

And I run:

```
cppclean foo.cpp
```

But it prints nothing and returns 0.

Am I doing something wrong? Are there any tutorials anywhere on how to use this tool?

Answer (score 2):

cppclean got updated in the meantime (June 2019) and includes now:

- Classes with virtual methods, no virtual destructor, and no bases
- Global/static data that are potential problems when using threads
- Functions that are declared but not defined
- Unnecessary forward class declarations
- Unnecessary function declarations
- Undeclared function definitions
- **Unnecessary #includes in header files**

  - No direct reference
    to anything in the header Header is unnecessary if classes were
    forward declared instead
  - Inconsistent case in #includes (foo.h versus
    Foo.h)

**Still not available :**

- (planned) Unnecessary #includes in source files
- (planned) Source files that reference headers not directly #included, ie, files
  that rely on a transitive #include from another header
- (planned) Unused members (private, protected, & public) methods and data
- (planned) using namespace std in header files
- (planned) Methods that
  are declared but not defined

**As a conclusion :**

```
cppclean .
```

should do the job now or alternatively :

```
cppclean <path>
```

[Further Information and Source](https://pypi.org/project/cppclean/)

Answer (score 0):

Run `cppclean .` inside your working directory where your *cpp* and *header files* are.
You need to provide all your source code to Cppclean, so that it could parse them and looking for problems.

To include multiple directory, see the [Run section of Cppclean's documentation](https://github.com/myint/cppclean#run).

Answer (score -5):

[The *cppclean* documentation](https://code.google.com/p/cppclean/) clearly states, right there on the front page, under "Features":

> - Find and print C++ language constructs: classes, methods, functions, etc.
> - Find classes with virtual methods, no virtual destructor, and no bases
> - Find global/static data that are potential problems when using threads
> - Unnecessary forward class declarations
> - Unnecessary function declarations
> - Undeclared function definitions
> - **(planned) Find unnecessary header files #included**
>
>   - **No direct reference to anything in the header**
>   - **Header is unnecessary if classes were forward declared instead**
> - (planned) Source files that reference headers not directly #included, ie, files that rely on a > - transitive #include from another header
> - (planned) Unused members (private, protected, & public) methods and data
> - (planned) Store AST in a SQL database so relationships can be queried

"Planned" means it is a feature that they are planning to add in the future. It is not there yet.

Comment: Snap! That's what _planned_ means? I'm so freakin' shocked!

Comment: That is the old homepage of the project. The new homepage (https://github.com/myint/cppclean) lists that feature as implemented.

Comment: Let's hope for standard headers they use the defined contents in the standard, not whatever it happens to be with the current revision of the implementation.